# Confused about normal force being a vector

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors

I was under the impression that forces including the normal force are vectors. If this is so, then why do we have formulas for normal force like $$F_{n}=mg\cos(\theta)$$
For an inclined plane. This evaluates to a scalar, so what am I missing here?

Comment: That is simply the magnitude of the normal force. To assign a vector to it you need to establish a coordinate system.

Answer (score 1):

$F_n$ is the magnitude of the normal force. $\vec{F}_n$ is the actual normal force ($\hat{n}$ is the unit normal vector). You could add a factor of $\hat{n}$ on the r.h.s. of your equation to get $$\vec{F}_n=\hat{n}mg\cos\theta$$ if you want to make a vector equation.

Or $$\vec{F}_n=-(\hat{n}\cdot\vec{w})\hat{n}$$ where $\vec{w}$ is the weight vector, if you want to be clever about it.

Comment: @Person, yes, the direction of the normal force is in the same direction as the normal vector for the surface that produces it.